# C# decompiler library to be embedded in android application?

Tags: android, library, java, c#, decompiler

Could you recommend a C# decompiler library to be embedded in my android application?

- input: file/file path
- output: parsed C# source code or similar

Prefered usage is just adding a jar to my project.